# Microsoft Edge javascript won't add class to button

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm using javascript to create a button with a hamburger icon. It works fine on every browser and OS except for Microsoft Edge on a Windows 10 Home PC.

Here's my code (just assume than any unnamed variables or functions were named earlier in the code):

```
function isMobile() {
    return window.outerWidth <= config.mobile.breakpointWidth
}

function toggleMobileClass() {
    isMobile() ? addClass(MBody, "mdcre-mobile") : removeClass(MBody, "mdcre-mobile")
}

function getMobileOpenIcon() {
    return '<i class="fa ' + config.mobile.navigation.button.icon.open + '"></i><span class="sr-only">Open Naviation</span>'
}

function getMobileCloseIcon() {
    return '<i class="fa ' + config.mobile.navigation.button.icon.close + '"></i><span class="sr-only">Close Navigation</span>'
}

function addMobileNavButton() {
    if (!document.getElementsByClassName("mdcre-nav-button")) {
        var e = document.createElement("button");
        e.classList += "mdcre-nav-button", e.innerHTML = getMobileOpenIcon(), e.addEventListener("click", function() {
            toggleMobileNavVisibility(), toggleMobileNavButtonIcon()
        }), MBody.appendChild(e)
    }
}

function removeMobileNavButton() {
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName("mdcre-nav-button")[0];
    e && e.remove()
}

function toggleMobileNavButton() {
    isMobile() ? addMobileNavButton() : removeMobileNavButton()
}

function toggleMobileNavVisibility() {
    document.getElementById("lightbox-menu").style.display = document.getElementById("lightbox-menu").style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';

      toggleClass(MHeader, 'show-nav');
      toggleClass(MBody, 'no-scroll');
}

function toggleMobileNavButtonIcon() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("mdcre-nav-button")[0].innerHTML = hasClass(MHeader, "show-nav") ? getMobileCloseIcon() : getMobileOpenIcon()
}
```

**Explanation**: When you go below a certain size (decided elsewhere by variable `breakpointWidth`), a `button` element is created and it is assigned the class `mdcre-nav-button`.

On Microsoft Edge, it creates the button element, but doesn't add the class.

I'm pretty sure the issue is with the function **"addMobileNavButton"**, although I can't figure out what is giving Microsoft Edge a hard time.

Other info: I'm only having problems with Microsoft Edge on a Windows 10 Home PC, recently updated. The code in Chrome and Firefox on the same PC work fine. I've tried Microsoft Edge on an iPhone 5c and it also worked fine.

Comment: Why are you using `+=` with the `classList`? It's not a string. Use `e.classList.add()`

Comment: And your syntax is weird. Why do you have multiple statements separated with comma instead of semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+=` is not the correct way to add a class to a `classList`. Use the `add()` method.

```
function addMobileNavButton() {
    if (!document.getElementsByClassName("mdcre-nav-button")) {
        var e = document.createElement("button");
        e.classList.add("mdcre-nav-button");
        e.innerHTML = getMobileOpenIcon();
        e.addEventListener("click", function() {
            toggleMobileNavVisibility(), toggleMobileNavButtonIcon()
        }), MBody.appendChild(e)
    }
}
```

You could also use `addClass(e, "mdcre-nav-button")`

Comment: That works! It's strange that the other browsers would still parse that syntax even though it was incorrect. Thank you so much!

Comment: It might have worked only because the class list was empty, since it's a new element. I also wonder why you didn't just use your `addClass()` function that's used earlier in the code.